# In Powershell, how do you build an array of table objects instead of an array of table names?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Building an array of table that match a list of table names, and then generate a script to build those tables:

```
$tablelist = @( 'TableBlah', 'TableWidget') 


#populate Tableset with tables that match the names in the array

ForEach ($item in $tablelist)
  { $tableset = $database.Tables  | where-object {$_.name -eq $item} }


#generate the script to build each table in the tableset
$tableset.ForEach(
 {$table.script() | out-file c:\temp\createtables.sql -append})
```

But it errors:

> [System.String] does not contain a method named 'script'

I presume because the tableset array is being treated as an array of strings so the `.script()` method isn't applicable

How do you create an array of table objects instead of strings of the table names?

I have also tried
`{$tableset =get-childitems $database.Tables  | where-object {$_.name -like $item} }`
but that errors with `get-childitem`:

> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters.

Or is there a better way to achieve this outcome?

Thanks

Comment: Correction, the code to generate the script should have been

ForEach ($table in $tableset)
{ 
  $table.script() | out-file c:\temp\createtablelocal.sql -append
}

Answer (score 0):

If `$database.Tables` is an array of tables then that is also what `$tableset` will be.  Doing either `($database.Tables).GetType()` or `$database.Tables | Get-Member` or both might help clear things up.  If it is an array of tables `Get-Member` will show you if indeed a script() method does exist or not as well as any other methods and properties available on the object or objects contained in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using *scripter* rather than just *script()* and that helped solve the problems, here is my working prototype (I still need to check what other scripter options also should be set, but this does generate output)

```
param 
( 
  
  $username = $(read-host "Username: "),
  $password = $(read-host "Password: ") 
)

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null 
    
$srv = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "servername" 
$srv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = $false
$srv.ConnectionContext.Login =  $username
$srv.ConnectionContext.Password = $password


$dbs=$srv.Databases['DBname']


$tablelist = @(
 'TableBlah',
 'TableWidget'

 
 ) 


$scripter = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter') $srv
$scripter.Options.ScriptSchema = $true
$scripter.Options.ScriptData = $false
$scripter.Options.ScriptDrops = $false

$listcnt=$tablelist.Count

$tablesout = @()


ForEach ($item in $tablelist)
{
    $tablesout += $dbs.Tables |  where-object {$_.name -like $item}
}

$outcnt=$tablesout.Count

$scripter.Script($tablesout) + "`r GO `r " | Out-File c:\temp\createtablesSQL.sql  

"$listcnt tables were requested, $outcnt were scripted"
```

> Blockquote